# Is the margin included in the whole width of the element in the default behaviour of the browsers?

Tags: html, css

I have doubts about the following question

On w3schools page, they are saying that the margin is included in the whole width

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

but on the mozzila documentation they are excluding the margin.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model#the_standard_css_box_model

So what is true ?

Comment: IF you read the not : Note: The margin is not counted towards the actual size of the box — sure, it affects the total space that the box will take up on the page, but only the space outside the box. The box's area stops at the border — it does not extend into the margin.

Comment: margin is never included in any box-sizing property (default is content-box). whether it is a border-box or content-box. find out more  at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: @Sfili_81 - There is not such a not on the w3schools page.

Comment: i mean in the mozilla docs.

Comment: @Sfili_81 it does not answer my question.I asked another thing.

Comment: Neither are wholly true. W3Schools omits any mention of box-sizing, MDN's explanation uses the term "box" incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Deep explanation is [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins). If You want to know how width is calculated for block elements see point `10.3.3`